# How to use multiprocessing on multiple files in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I need to process thousands of files and would like to use parallel processing to save some time.

```
import os
import re
import csv
import numpy as np

rawdata="/content/drive/My Drive/somepath"
outfolder="/content/drive/My Drive/somepath2"
if not os.path.exists(outfolder):
    os.makedirs(outfolder)  

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rawdata):
    for file in sorted(filenames):   
        filename = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(dirpath), file)
        fileno = re.search('(.*?)\.', file).group(1)
        print("check " + fileno)
        if not os.path.exists(outfolder+'/'+fileno+'.csv'):
            print("Processing " + filename)
            #run a bunch of stuff
            with open(outfolder+'/'+fileno+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
                wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                wr.writerow(a bunch of stuff)           
                
print('\n job done!!')
```

I tried `multiprocessing` as follows. The code didn't raise any error but somehow it was still processing a same file for 20 minutes. Normally processing each file takes 2 minutes. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def process_file(file):
    fileno = re.search('(.*?)\.', file).group(1)
    print("check " + fileno)
    if not os.path.exists(outfolder+'/'+fileno+'.csv'):
            print("Processing " + filename)
            #run a bunch of stuff
            with open(outfolder+'/'+fileno+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
                wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                wr.writerow(a bunch of stuff)  

pool = mp.Pool(4)
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rawdata):
    for file in sorted(filenames):  
      pool.apply_async(process_file, [file]) 

pool.close()
pool.join()

print('\n job done!!')
```

Comment: Is it gonna help you is the first question you should ask yourself?

Comment: What is disk access and memory usage like while this runs? If you go over available RAM, or the disk channel is fully committed, some jobs will take a long time because they are waiting for resources.

Comment: `...still processing a same file for 20 minutes.` - is there anything different about this file?

Comment: Its not so much what happens to a single process but whether the entire work load is done faster. Is the whole job done but one is waiting for 20 mintues? If this is a modest machine with 4 cores and tight on RAM, and if there is no way that process should take 20 minutes.... then its a hint that one fewer cores may be a good idea.

Comment: Alternately, it could be that the process raised an error and since you don't consume the results of the `apply_async`, you never notice. Consider getting the list of files to process, call the pool's `imap_unordered` and consume the results. Or put try/except in the worker and log errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work ,

```
    files = [ ]
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rawdata):
        files.extend ( filenames )
    with mp.Pool( 4 ) as p:
        p.map( process_file , files )
```

Comment: This would start a new pool for each subdirectory and wait for completion of those files before moving to the next. This will tend to idle processes while the "tall poll" for each directory completes. I don't see how this does better than OP's solution.

Comment: 4 processes are taken to action at a time , every pool takes new file to process once current file processed.

Comment: You wait for pool completion and restart the pool for each subdirectory. Suppose there were 100 subdirectories with 1 file apiece. 3 processes would remain idle on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: i updated my answer for your condition. pls give your opinion

Comment: That's close, except that the filenames need directories added. Perhaps `files.extend(os.path.join(dirpath, filename) for filename in filenames)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

    fileno = re.search('(.*?)\.', file).group(1)
    print("check " + fileno)
    if not os.path.exists(outfolder+'/'+fileno+'.csv'):
        print("Processing " + filename)
        #run a bunch of stuff
        with open(outfolder+'/'+fileno+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
            wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            wr.writerow(a bunch of stuff)


def main():
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rawdata):
        for file in sorted(filenames):
        pool.apply_async(process_file, [file])

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print('\n job done!!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This may get you closer to a solution by catching and reporting errors plus putting some timing information in the output. This example uses a map function with chunksize 1 so that the worker gets new work items 1 at a time. This works well when there is a lot of worker processing per work item.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def process_file(file):
    try:
        start = time.time()
        fileno = re.search('(.*?)\.', file).group(1)
        print("check " + fileno)
        if not os.path.exists(outfolder+'/'+fileno+'.csv'):
                print("Processing " + filename)
                #run a bunch of stuff
                with open(outfolder+'/'+fileno+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
                    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                    wr.writerow(a bunch of stuff)
        return "Success: {}, {} seconds".format(file, time.time()-start)  
    except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        return "Error: {}\n{}\n{} seconds".format(file, traceback.format_exc(), time.time()-start)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":

    files_to_process = [os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rawdata)
        for filename in filenames]
        
    with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
        start = time.time()
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(process_file, files_to_process, chunksize=1):
            print("{}: {}".format(time.time()-start, result)
    
    print('\n job done!!')
```